# Method with MySql query for LOAD DATA IN FILE never finishes

Tags: c#, mysql

I am populating a MySQL table in C# using the `LOAD DATA INFILE` method.

Therefore I wrote a method for creating the query string...

```
public static string LoadDataInFile(string TempCsv, string MatchId)
        {
            StringBuilder MySqlString = new StringBuilder();

            MySqlString.AppendFormat(@"LOAD DATA INFILE '{0}' INTO TABLE {1}_trackingdata 
                FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
                IGNORE 1 LINES", TempCsv, MatchId);
            return MySqlString.ToString();
        }
```

and one that executes raw queries:

```
public static void ExecuteRawQuery(string Query, string ConnectionString)
        {
            using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString.ToString()))
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();

                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(Query, conn);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    conn.Close();
                    Console.WriteLine("Import probably done...");
                    return;
                }
                catch (MySqlException SqlException)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
                    Console.WriteLine("SqlException: {0}", SqlException.Message);
                    Console.WriteLine("Exit program.");
                    Console.ResetColor();

                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }
            }
        }
```

The table gets populated as expected (checked with Sequel Pro), but the application never continues.

```
public static void Main(string[] args) 
{
  // ...
  ExecuteRawQuery(LoadDataInFile("myFile.csv", "123456"));
  Console.WriteLine("I will never be displayed..");
  // ...
}
```

Is there any reason why `ExecuteRawQuery()` never finishes? When I execute other queries (SELECT, UPDATE) everything works as expected.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code by putting a break point on the call to `ExecuteRawQuery(LoadDataInFile("myFile.csv", "123456"));` and pressing F11 to step into the call?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but using the `MySqlClient.MySqlBulkLoader`-class solves the problem. Leaving this here for anybody experiencing the same issue:

```
public static void ImportCSV(string CSV, string TableName, string ConnectionString)
        {
            using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString.ToString()))
            {
                MySqlBulkLoader Bulkloader = new MySqlBulkLoader(conn);

                Bulkloader.TableName = TableName;
                Bulkloader.FileName = CSV;
                Bulkloader.Timeout = 0;
                Bulkloader.NumberOfLinesToSkip = 1;
                Bulkloader.FieldTerminator = ";";

                var result = Bulkloader.Load();
                Console.WriteLine("Imported {0} rows into the database", result);
            }

        }
```